# php upload weirdness: Header shows up only

Tags: php, file-upload, header

i'm stumped. I created a reservation page in Bluefish and Dreamweaver. When I open a preview in Safari I get the php page I created. With exemption of the Google reCAPTCHA:

http://theatervonk.be/afbeeldingen/previeuw_mac.png

When I upload the same page to my server I get only the header: http://www.theatervonk.be/reservaties.php

I can't seem to find something wrong in the code, but I must overlooking something...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Reservaties</title>
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" HREF="afbeeldingen/vonk_phpstyle.css" TYPE="text/css">
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  <center> <table width="908" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="281"><img src="afbeeldingen/vonk_logo.gif"  width="281" height="280"></td>
        <td width="339">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="339" style="background-image:url(afbeeldingen/menu_vonk.png); background-repeat:no-repeat"><div id="navigation"> <?php echo do_main_nav() ; ?></div></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
   </center>
    <!-- end .header --></div>
  <div class="content">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="send.php">
      <table width="908" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="302" rowspan="9" align="left" valign="top"><table width="908" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="302" rowspan="12" align="left" valign="top"><h5>Je kan reserveren door te mailen naar: <a href="mailto:reserveringen@theatervonk.be">reserveringen@theatervonk.be</a> of bellen naar 0486 611 447.</h5>
<h5>Geef volgende gegevens door:</h5>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <h5>Datum van de voorstelling</h5>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <h5>Aantal plaatsen</h5>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <h5>Soort kaarten en prijs</h5>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <h5>Uw telefoonnummer</h5>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <h5>Uw adres en e-mailadres als u op de hoogte wilt blijven van onze voorstellingen</h5>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <h5>(zie ook het verzendformulier hiernaast)</h5>
              <h2>Betalen</h2>
              <h5>Triodos: BE86 5230 8029 4150</h5>
              <h2>Audities</h2>
              <h5>Wil je graag een auditie meedoen, meld je aan!</h5>
              <h2>Reacties op voorstellingen</h2>
              <h5>Wij zijn altijd heel blij uw reactie op onze voorstellingen te lezen! Uw mailtje is dan ook heel welkom! </h5>
              <h5><a href="mailto:info@theatervonk.be">info@theatervonk.be</a> Of laat een berichtje achter op ons gastenboek.</h5></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="middle"><h1>Kaarten bestellen:</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="7" align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="215" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" valign="middle">&quot;Creme au beurre&quot;</td>
            <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><p>
              <input type="checkbox" name="kaarten[]" value="19 oktober 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms" />
              <label for="19 oktober 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms">19 oktober 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms</label>
            </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="kaarten[]" value="26 oktober 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms" />
                <label for="26 oktober 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms">26 oktober 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="kaarten[]" value="21 december 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms" />
                <label for="21 december 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms">21 december 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="kaarten[]" value="18 januari 2015 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms" />
                <label for="18 januari 2015 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms">18 januari 2015 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="kaarten[]" value="15 februari 2015 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms" />
                <label for="15 februari 2015 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms">15 februari 2015 10u30 Cafe Kiebooms</label>
              </p>
              <p>Gratis, maar wel reserveren!</p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" valign="middle">&quot;Wie is er bang voor Virginia Woolf?&quot;</td>
            <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><p>
              <input type="checkbox" name="kaarten[]" value="17 oktober 2014 - 20u. Zwarte Komedie" />
              <label for="17 oktober 2014 - 20u. Zwarte Komedie">17 oktober 2014 - 20u. Zwarte Komedie</label>
            </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="kaarten[]" value="18 oktober 2014 - 20u. Zwarte Komedie" />
                <label for="18 oktober 2014 - 20u. Zwarte Komedie">18 oktober 2014 - 20u. Zwarte Komedie</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="kaarten[]" value="19 oktober 2014 - 15u. Zwarte Komedie" />
                <label for="19 oktober 2014 - 15u. Zwarte Komedie">19 oktober 2014 - 15u. Zwarte Komedie</label>
              </p>
              <p>10 euro / 2 euro (Omniostatuut)</p></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right"><label for="tickets">Aantal kaarten en prijs:</label></td>
            <td colspan="2"><textarea name="tickets" id="tickets" cols="55" rows="5" >Hier opstommen, aub</textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right"><label for="naam">Naam:</label></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" />
              (<img src="afbeeldingen/verplicht_veld.gif" width="8" height="8">) </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right">Straat:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="straat" id="straat" />
              (<img src="afbeeldingen/verplicht_veld.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8">) </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right">Postcode:</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input name="postcode" type="text" id="postcode" size="5" maxlength="4" />
              (<img src="afbeeldingen/verplicht_veld.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8">) </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right"><label for="plaats">Gemeente:</label></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="plaats" id="plaats" />
              (<img src="afbeeldingen/verplicht_veld.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8">) </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right"><label for="tel">Tel:</label></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" />
              (<img src="afbeeldingen/verplicht_veld.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8">) </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right"><label for="mail">E-mail:</label></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><?php
           require_once('recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // you got this from the signup page
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
          ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td> (<img src="afbeeldingen/verplicht_veld.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8">) Verplicht veld</td>
            <td width="113" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="Verzenden" id="Verzenden" value="Verzenden" /></td>
            <td width="278" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="reset" name="Wissen" id="Wissen" value="Wissen" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>          <h5>&nbsp;</h5></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <div class="footer">
    <blockquote>
      <p><font color="#660033" size="-3" face="Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif"><a href="https://login.one.com/mail" target="_blank">Webmail</a>
        <!-- end .footer --></p>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
<!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, as it seems to crash right on: `<?php echo do_main_nav() ; ?>` what happens there? I can't see anything in this code that has the PHP function that it relates to? Did you perhaps forget an include somewhere?

Comment: Try error reporting .. add this to the top of your page `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>`

Comment: A better question would be why it works when running it locally, when the function isn't defined. Probably different error reporting default settings.

Comment: @Barmar See my answer—I'm assuming that the "local preview" wasn't done through a PHP server, so the `<?php ...>` content is just treated as an unknown HTML element.

Comment: I did @Fluffeh!
I don't know why it works locally,@Barmar . I usually work with Taco HTML Edit but for PHP I found it not working well so I tried some other programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output stops just before `<?php echo do_main_nav() ; ?>`. So that function's not present or not working. Check your server PHP error log to find out the exact error, and proceed from there.

I'd guess that the reason it works in your Safari preview is that you're not previewing it using a PHP server, so the `<?php ... >` is just treated as an unknown type of HTML element, and ignored. I notice your preview doesn't actually seem to feature a main navigation, which seems to be a bit of a clue.

Given that `do_main_nav()` isn't a built-in PHP function, and that the call to it is the first PHP in your page, I'd assume you'd forgotten an `include()` somewhere, but I don't know enough about Bluefish or Dreamweaver to know how that function is meant to be provided, assuming it's come from them.

Comment: Damn, I feel stupid now. Thanks @Matt. I hadn't finished my navigation code yet. So I hadn't included it, yet. If I leave the <?php echo do_main_nav() ; ?> out I got my page online. Just have to finish my navigation code now.